# Very high frequency out of SPI pin in ATmega16A

Tags: avr, atmega, spi, high-frequency

I was trying to interface [ATmega16A](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8154-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16A_Datasheet.pdf) with ENC28J60, and I was facing problems with it, so I decided to physically look at the signals b/w the master µC and the Ethernet chip using an oscilloscope. But to my surprise I am getting a very high freq wave out of the SCK pin which is around 15MHz.
Now here are some debugging I have tried.
No problem with USBasp programmer because the UART code is working perfectly.
No problem with the circuit connection as the UART is working and I am able to display any text on my laptop perfectly.
No problem with the clock fed as I've used both external crystal, internal clock and both give me the same error.
No problem with the µC as I have changed it many times and all of them behave in the same way.  I'll upload the code that i am using to initilize and transmit using SPI.

Please give me your suggestion and possible debugging tips. Thanks in advance.

here is my SPI initialization function.

```
 void SPI_initialize()
 {
   //configure MOSI, SCK and SSbar as output pin and MISO as input pin.
  DDRB  = (1<<4)|(1<<5)|(1<<7);
  //Prescaler: Fosc/128, Enable Interrupts, I have changed these values to Fosc/2,4,64
  SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR)|(1<<SPR0)|(1<<SPR1);
  SPSR = (0<<SPI2X);
  }
```

Comment: What is the system clock frequency?

Comment: System Clock : 12MHz, crystal oscillator, and using decoupling capacitors.

Comment: This project is just killing me, they say SPI is very easy, but ever since I started interfacing ENC28J60 with my µC I've been hitting the wall almost on an hourly basis, with this high frequency case being the latest.

Comment: Not possible for an AVR with a 12MHz XTAL to generate a 15MHz clock.  Are you certain you aren't looking at the CLKOUT pin of the ENC28J60?  Could your scope be aliasing the signal?

Comment: @M D,Nope, I'm connecting scope b/w the SCK pin and common ground. And I changed the scope twice. I used a DSO and then an analog scope with both over a range of 50MHz. I have no clue what is causing this.